# Excel formula to prevent duplicate name entries

Tags: excel, formula

I am creating a work chart for a project with excel table. However with so many people to manage I have ran into an issue of often putting same person twice on different columns of the same row (he/she can't work on two places at same time!)

So, I am looking for help with a formula that notices if the same name appears twice on a row but does not count multiple blank cells as duplicates. My understanding of excel is very basic and so far I have managed to get this far

=COUNTIF(A6:W6;A6:W6)=1

which returns to me with false, which I assume is because of the blank, unfilled cells still within the table being counted as duplicates.

Help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have a range as the second argument of a Countif. The range you pass into the formula will resolve to just the first value. Use the Evaluate Formula tool to see what I mean.

If you want to determine if ANY name in the range A1:W1 appears more than once (and exclude blanks), you will need a recursive function. That can only be done with VBA, not with a formula.

You could use a Countif in a conditional format to highlight duplicate names in a row. That's a piece of cake. Pipe up if you want to do that.

Comment: I just added a bit about Conditional Formats. Please read that, too.